# Packing all CSS/JS links into an included PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

After years of using spaghetti code to write my PHP projects, I have opted to switch over to using Code Igniter just to get some experience with a MVC Framework (Yeah, I know its dying but Laravel/Composer blew brain).

I have a site theme I purchased years back and decided to use it while experimenting with creating Views. The particular theme has a massive amount of JS links though due to not being optimized but rather just showing all features.

Is there any issues with just placing all of the Header content into a PHP file and then including it into the the actual View file?

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/spinner/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/charts/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/charts/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/charts/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/charts/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/charts/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/charts/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/uniform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.cleditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.autosize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.dualListBox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.inputlimiter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/wizard/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/wizard/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/wizard/jquery.form.wizard.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/uploader/plupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/uploader/plupload.html5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/uploader/plupload.html4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/uploader/jquery.plupload.queue.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/tables/datatable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/tables/tablesort.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/tables/resizable.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.collapsible.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.progress.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.timeentry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.colorpicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.jgrowl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.breadcrumbs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.sourcerer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.elfinder.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/charts/chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: Header content means all of your **`<link>`** and **`<script>`** in one file and include that into a view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible for your local files. Of course you need two php files - one for your css and one for your JS.

Here is an example

```
<?PHP

  header("content-type: application/javascript");

  $all_your_js_ressources = array(
      'libs/foo.js',
      'libs/bar.js',
      'modules/foo.module.js',
      'modules/bar.module.js',
      'plugins/foo.plugin.js',
      'plugins/bar.plugin.js',
      'main.js'
  );

  foreach ($all_your_js_ressources as $filename) {
      readfile( $filename );echo "\r\n";
  }

?>
```

Comment: +1 - Don't forget to set your Content-Type header ;)